# how to segment dataset without duplicating data in R?

Tags: r

I wish to segment a grouped data via certain overlapping Date ranges which I have managed by the following.

```
library(dplyr)

## Create data frames
df_A = data.frame( "ID" = rep("A" , 5) , "Date" = c( "2000-01-03" , "2000-02-03" , "2000-04-01" , "2000-05-03" ,"2000-05-04" ) , "Var_1"=c(1,2,3,4,5) ) 

df_B = data.frame( "ID" = rep("B" , 5) , "Date" = c( "2000-01-03" , "2000-01-04" , "2000-01-05" , "2000-03-02" ,"2000-04-01" ) , "Var_1"=c(6,7,8,9,10) )

df_C = data.frame( "ID" = rep("C" , 5) , "Date" = c( "2000-01-03" , "2000-02-03" , "2000-03-01" , "2000-04-03" ,"2000-05-04" ) , "Var_1"=c(11,12,13,14,15) )

## Bind and group data frames together via ID
mydf = bind_rows( df_A , df_B , df_C ) %>% group_by( ID )

## Create date range
filterDates = data.frame( "start" = c("2000-01-01" , "2000-02-01","2000-03-01","2000-04-01" ) , "end" = c( "2000-02-29","2000-03-31","2000-04-30","2000-05-31" ) )

## Segment data according to date range
segmented_df = apply( filterDates , 1 , function(x) filter( mydf , Date>= as.Date (x["start"]) & Date<=x["end"]  ) )
```

However, the process creates duplicates of the data within some of the list.

```
## For e.g.
segmented_df[[2]][1,] ## This was already in segmented_df[[1]][2,]
```

How can I do so while avoiding the duplication of data ?

I thought of using group_by( ID , Date ) but that wouldn't account for the date range.

Note: I am not looking for a particular form of solution but it will be preferable if it is memory efficient and "easy" to call each complete segmented group.

I apologize in advance if I used any incorrect terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can try unique instead of group_by

```
 mydf = bind_rows( df_A , df_B , df_C ) %>% unique( ID )
```